# select-box overflowing a td

Tags: html, css, select, overflow, html-table

In my table i have some td's with some select-boxes.
The one the user is clicking becomes a real selectbox (with size="n") instead of a dropdown.

But I dont whant the table td to change its height.

```
<table><tr>
    <td>
    <select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>duck</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select size="5">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>batman</option>
        <option>chewing gum</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>monitor</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

eg: how it looks:

[image: how it looks]

what i want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/dCzDE/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="back">
<table border="0"><tr>
    <td>
    <select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>duck</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select size="5">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>batman</option>
        <option>chewing gum</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>monitor</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
td{vertical-align:top;}
.back{background:green; height:28px; display:inline-block}
```

Hope this helps.

*PS: I have taken a green background instead of your pink. You can replace it.*

Comment: It is not now. Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dCzDE/2/ - @PeterVR

Comment: agreed, but doesn't behave like a table anymore now. You could just as well remove all the tbale markup and work with span's then... http://jsfiddle.net/dCzDE/3/

Answer (score 1):

Tables work a bit strange when it comes to overflowing. You can't just set a fixed height and an overflow visible, like you would do with normal block level elements.

The only solution I can think of, is to position you select absolute, to take it out of the flow, and position it on top of the cell you wanted it to be in. You will have to set a width for that cell however, as it will technically become empty, and get no width at all.

The css to achieve this would look something like this:

```
td { 
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100px;
}
td select[size="5"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

And a fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/xRav2/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Table tags. I think this can be achieved using DIV tags as follows:

```
<style> div{ border:1px solid #000;float:left;} </style>
<div>
<div><select size="1">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>duck</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <div>
    <select size="1">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <select size="5">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>yes</option>
            <option>batman</option>
            <option>chewing gum</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <select size="1">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>monitor</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
     <select size="1">
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>monitor</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```